# Plot gets stuck whenever I click on it

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

```
import sys
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import deque

port = "COM11"
baud = 9600
timeout=1

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = port
ser.baudrate = baud
ser.timeout = timeout


a1 = deque([0.0]*100)
#ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 1000))



line, = plt.plot(a1)
plt.ion()
plt.ylim([0,1000])

try:
  ser.open()
except:
  sys.stderr.write("Error opening serial port %s\n" % (ser.portstr) )
  sys.exit(1)

#ser.setRtsCts(0)

while 1:
     # Read from serial port, blocking
     data = ser.read(1)

     # If there is more than 1 byte, read the rest
     n = ser.inWaiting()
     data = data + ser.read(n)
     #sys.stdout.write(data)
     print(a1)

     a1.appendleft((data))
     datatoplot = a1.pop()
     line.set_ydata(a1)
     plt.draw()
```

I am getting the plot but whenever I click on the plot window to say move the window to different place on the screen the plot gets stuck it says not responding on the plot window.I am getting this problem whenever I use real time plotting , if I simply pass an array and plot then I do not get this problem.Please tell if there is a problem with the code or some other problem like low processing power although I am using 32GB RAM on my system.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're just not running out of serial data and choking on `data = ser.read(1)`?

Comment: yeah, I am sure about that because the problem only happens if I click on plot window and if I do not click anything then everything is fine and I am able to observe the plot for as much time I require